# php array is outputting as Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to php, my array is outputting as Array.  Is their a way to pull out the imploded comma delimited string into its real value?

```
$result = $sql->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
$rows[]=$row;
}
$result->close();
$sql->close();
$all = implode(',', $rows);
echo $all
```

output:

```
Array,Array,Array,Array
```

Comment: Do: `print_r($rows);` and you will see the structure of your array and, that you have to do: `array_map(function($v){echo implode(",", $v);}, $rows);`

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks this worked! But my array isn't showing as comma delimited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using

```
 $result = $sql->query($query);
        $rows = array(); 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[]=$row;
        }
        $result->close();
        $sql->close();
        $str = implode(',', array_map(function($el){ return $el['username']; }, $rows));
        echo $str;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `print_r($all)` to view the array contents.

Comment: its still printing out as Array using print_r